# Try Catch in Jenkins File

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am very new to jenkins pipeline and groovy . Please ignore environment variable i will use it in future

Here i want to send start to slack and upon git pull if have to send success or failure based on project status. I am getting error at try for something

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { 
        val = 1
    }
    stages {
        stage('Started') {
            steps{
                slackSend(message: "STARTED")
            }
        }

        try {
            stage('SCM Checkout') {
                steps {
                    git url:'https://github.com/Abhishek24094/dev.git'
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            slackSend(message: "Failure")
        }

        stage('finished') {
            steps{
                slackSend(message: "STARTED")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Adding proper formatting to your code will make life easier for you and all readers here on StackOverflow. And maybe your colleagues ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#declarative-versus-scripted-pipeline-syntax) (as indicated by the `pipeline` step in line 1).

This does not allow you to run plain Groovy code (such as `try`), but builds around pre-defined steps (`agent`,`environment`, `stage` etc.).

The good news for you is that you don't need this error handling. Instead, [`post`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) allows you to run steps after the the build based on success or failure:

```
pipeline {
    // ..
    post {
        success {
            slackSend ( message: "STARTED")
        }
        failure { 
            slackSend ( message: "Failure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question from naive : from where can i learn more about jenkins file.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/ and maybe https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/declarative-jenkins-pipelines